# php out of memory error

Tags: php, ram, memory-limit

During a symphony2 php product installation I receive

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 190578688) (tried to allocate 1048576 bytes)
```

In php.ini memory_limit is -1.

In my virtual server I have 2GB of RAM: may be I need more RAM?

Comment: Have you tried to set your `memory_limit` to `1024M` or something else?

Comment: the amount of physical ram in your server isn't the problem. Your PHP's still limited to only ~182meg, and your app tried to use more than that. Add all the ram you want to the server, but it's the PHP memory_limit you have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Some `php` installations tend to have separate `php.ini` files for `Apache` and `CLI` (command line). You are installing `Symfony2`, I suspect that you are doing this using `composer` on `cli`.

Check what is your file structure for your php installation. If there are two `ini`'s, one under /apache, and one under /cli, you know what to do :)

Also try setting `memory_limit` for big, but sane value. Having at least 8 gb of ram it's good idea to set it between 2 and 4 gigs. This is because sometimes you can fall into never-ending loop that eats your ram (for example try `var_dump()` on `Doctrine` resultset, or just have fun with recurrence), and render your system unresponsive if there isn't any memory limit for `php`. Hope this helps :)